# Call Bokeh Server App Python Function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am searching for a way to call a python function of my Bokeh Server App from arbitrary Javascript. I want to write custom widgets using HTML/Javascript only and use them to interact with the Bokeh App. [I know that one can extend bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html#structure-of-bokeh-models). Is this is the only way to go? For fast prototyping I think it would be nice to just use the websocket connection to send requests to the app, something along this line:

```
Bokeh.call('my_python_func', arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0` this capability does not yet exist directly in the library. You can follow the GitHub issue [**`#5983`** Events with feedback / Simple RPC](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5983) to get updates about any ongoing development.

Otherwise, any alternatives are somewhat involved. If the Python you would like to call is available behind some REST API you could certainly invoke that from JS using standard means.